# How to disable security on actuator endpoints on spring boot 1.5 with spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with secure API on port 8080, using `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation. The management port is changed to 8081 and is not exposed to the public so I don't need/want to have security enabled on the actuator endpoints

On Spring Boot 1.4 it was possible to use property `management.security.enabled=false` to ignore all actuator endpoints from security. I understand that this functionality was considered a "mistake", and Boot 1.5 "corrects" this by removing this auto-configuration if `@EnableWebSecurity` is present. The release notes state that we have to explicitly configure this ourselves in this case.

Does this mean we have to pull this out of 1.4 source and implement in each app, or is there a new way of achieving this?

Comment: you can exclude the actuator endpoints from going through authentication like this 

        http.antMatchers("/internal/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
           ....